# How to get Cogntio User claims and set in UserManager.AddClaimAsync (Asp.Net Identity Provider))

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito

I m not sure my following approach is right or not. But here it is

I have an application where Asp.net identity is implemented. Now I m implementing AWS Cognito User Pool for user signup and sign in. On Sign in I m using the following method to get user token from Cognito

```
 CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(this.POOL_ID, this.CLIENTAPP_ID, provider);
     CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username, this.CLIENTAPP_ID, userPool, provider);

 InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
 {
        Password = password
 };

 AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
 if (authResponse.AuthenticationResult != null)
 {
   //Here user token is found
 }
```

After successful login with Cognito User, I get the user token. As I m using.Net Identity, I want to extract claim from this Cognito User token and add like this

```
UserManager.AddClaimAsync("UserId", new Claim("SomeClaimType", "SomeToken"));
```

So that User authentication and Authorisation work as it is as it was working with Asp.Net Identity

Please advice